# Formatting a cell to a percentage in PHPExcel

Tags: php, formatting, phpexcel, percentage

I am automating an excel spreadsheet using PHP.

I have been looking for a way to pragmatically format a cell to a percentage in PHPExcel.

I want to change a value like

> 0.077922078

to

> 8%

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use ceil() to round to closest number and than append % before putting it in ur excel file..http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Answer (score 45, accepted):

assuming your cell is A1 ..

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()->applyFromArray( 
        array( 
            'code' => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00
        )
    );
```

Comment: I guess that to get a straight percentage i.e. 2% i need to remove the _00 form FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00 ?

Comment: Use PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE to display as an integer percentage; of "0.0%" or "0.000%" etc to display one or three decimal places.... or indeed any string that corresponds to a valid Excel number format mask

Comment: taking off `_00` is the key!!! I tried it and it works like charm! Thank you @Chris

Comment: good to see my questions being used :D good luck! thanks for the appreciation!

Answer (score 3):

PHPExcel library has predefined only few basic formatting constants. You can actually build your own for virtually any purpose (coloring, formatting decimals & thousands etc). Formatting capabilities in Excel are huge. Following will format percent with 3 decimal places and coloring negative values to red:

```
$workSheet
    ->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('0.000%;[Red]-0.000%');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$colLetter = "A";
$rowNumber = "1";

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle("$colLetter:$rowNumber")
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->applyFromArray([
        "code" => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE
    ]);
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of what your answer adds to the other.

Comment: Yes of course you have right @gp_sflover, but I thought this piece of code was self-describing :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is seeing this after PHPExcel turns to PHPSpreadsheet.

PHPSpreadsheet have a dedicated function to apply format codes. So, to set a number as percentage now we need to replace `applyFromArray()` to `setFormatCode()` as follow:

```php
$spreadsheet
   ->getActiveSheet()
   ->getStyle("A1")
   ->getNumberFormat()
   ->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00);
```

**Note**: `setFormatCode()` seems to not support to apply to a entire column/row. So, if it is your case, you will need to create a loop over column/row to apply for each cell individually.

Comment: setFormatCode is a function in PHPExcel. The applyFromArray is used to set multiple styles as once. Also, you can uase "A1:E10" for the cell ID to set a format to multiple cells.