# How to show percentage values in decimal in PHPExcel chart?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpexcel

I created a chart using [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library and enabled percentage value :

```
 $layout1->setShowPercent(TRUE);
```

but percentage doesn't show decimal values.

Example: `0.33%` is shown as `0%` like here :

[image: Percentage error image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()->applyFromArray( 
    array( 
        'code' => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00
    )
);
```

[not sure if this will apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428767/formatting-a-cell-to-a-percentage-in-phpexcel)

[PHPExcel Formats](http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Style/PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat.html#constFORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00)

Comment: Not working... :(, after appliying this code, the value was changed 2 to 200.00%, i want to change percentage display format only,  not value

Comment: @RathileshChundaran - technically, that isn't a value change.... try setting a  cell value as `2` and then applying a percentage format in MS Excel itself